# Is it possible to send a keyboard without sending text or a message at telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I try to send and delete the message but not working

```
if($new = $bot->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $call_chat_id,
            'text' => ' ',
            'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
            'reply_markup' => $choose,
        ])){
            $bot->deleteMessage([
                'chat_id' => $chat_id,
                'message_id' => $new['message_id']
            ]);
}
```

am using [Telegram-bot-simple](https://github.com/Mukxtarov/Telegram-bot-simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to send keyboard without sending a message

Comment: but your message can be invisible if the character can not be seen ;-)